# What is the default padding for TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, material-design

What is the default value used in `contentPadding` property inside `InputDecoration()` for `TextField` or `TextFormField` in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Flutter documentation here: [Flutter > material > InputDecoration > contentPadding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/contentPadding.html)

> By default the `contentPadding` reflects [isDense] and the type of the [border].
>
> If [isCollapsed] is true then `contentPadding` is [EdgeInsets.zero].
>
> If `isOutline` property of [border] is false and if [filled] is true then `contentPadding` is `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 8, 12, 8)` when [isDense] is true and `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12)` when [isDense] is false.
>
> If `isOutline` property of [border] is false and if [filled] is false then `contentPadding` is `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 8)` when [isDense] is true and `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 0, 12)` when [isDense] is false.
>
> If `isOutline` property of [border] is true then `contentPadding` is `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 20, 12, 12)` when [isDense] is true and `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 24, 12, 16)` when [isDense] is false.

**NOTE:** The value of `isOutline` property is `true` for `OutlineInputBorder()` and is `false` for `UnderlineInputBorder()`